# The server tag is not well formed

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the following image button on the GridView and I want to call the OnClientClick to call javascript method with passing a parameter. I am getting Server Tag is not well formed error. I tried changing double quotes to single quote etc, still the same issue.

```
OnClientClick="return ConfirmOnDelete('<%#Eval("Name")%>');"

<asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/images/fbclose.png" AlternateText="Delete"  runat="server" OnClientClick="return ConfirmOnDelete('<%#Eval("Name")%>');"/>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use single quotes around the `OnClientClick` property:

```
OnClientClick='return ConfirmOnDelete(<%#Eval("Name")%>);'
```

You also had an orphaned single quote after the `Eval` function. If you need to wrap the value that you're passing into the function with quotes, you can do this:

```
OnClientClick='return confirmOnDelete(\"<%#Eval("Name")%>\");'
```

Comment: additionally, there was an errant `'` in his code which you removed, but did not point out :)

Comment: Yes, I noted that in my answer, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Actually, you're right. I must have removed my comment about the orphaned quote during an edit.

Comment: For passing a value into a function with quotes, this doesn't seem to work for me. Instead, the function outputs like confirmOnDelete(\&quot;&lt;%# Eval(&quot;Name&quot;) %>\&quot;);"

Answer (score 0):

OnClientClick="return ConfirmOnDelete(<%#Eval("Name")%>') you only have one single quote at the end  change it to

```
OnClientClick='return ConfirmOnDelete(<%#Eval("Name")%>)'
```