# Right syntax of Button Onclick Event in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I use a `repeater Control` to display all the comments from `Datatable`:

```
COMMENT(id,content,time);
```

In repeater I insert a button `Delete` to Delete that correlative comment

I wonder if I can add an variable "`string id`" in `ButtonDelete_Click()` like:

```
protected void ButtonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, string id)
{
     int idcm = Convert.ToInt32(id);
     string sql = "delete from COMMENT where ID=" + idcm;
     l.EXECUTEQUERYSQL(sql);
     ErrorTrap("DONE");//alert deleted sucessfully
}
```

And in aspx page:

```
<Repeater...>
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete comment" 
         OnClick="ButtonDelete_Click(<%#Eval("MA_COMMENT") %>)"/>
    ....
</Repeater>
```

But when I build this page, an error ocur: `The server tag is not well formed.` at line:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete comment" 
     OnClick="ButtonDelete_Click(<%#Eval("MA_COMMENT") %>)"/>
```

It is the first time I use Repeater Control, so I really dont know how is the right syntax? And I wonder if I can add more variales in ButtonDelete_Click Event or not???

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the command argument property fot the button and grap it in the click event :

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete comment" 
         OnClick="ButtonDelete_Click()" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("MA_COMMENT") %>'/>
```

on the click event

```
void ButtonDelete (object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

     var id = int.parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

  }
```

Hope this is helpful

Comment: thanks, but in cs page, it has an error: cannot resolve symbol CommandArgument. Help???

Comment: Thank, I use void ButtonDelete (object sender,  CommandEventArgs e) and then call it: OnCommand="ButtonDelete_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("MA_COMMENT") %>' --> It works, thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
OnClick='ButtonDelete_Click(<%#Eval("MA_COMMENT") %>)'
```

or try replacing `'` to `"` it should work.

### Edit 1

More details

1. [The server tag is not well formed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814383/the-server-tag-is-not-well-formed)
2. [The server tag is not well formed.(databinder.eval)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993565/the-server-tag-is-not-well-formed-databinder-eval)
3. [error The server tag is not well formed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570572/error-the-server-tag-is-not-well-formed)
4. [The server tag is not well formed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278616/the-server-tag-is-not-well-formed-error)

Comment: thank you, but when I replace ' to ", it still doesnt work: CS1040: Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line